# ASP.NET GridView and UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview, updatepanel, postback

I have a `GridView`, inside a `UserControl`, inside an `UpdatePanel` on a page.

There's a `Button` in the `GridView` which needs to fire a `PostBack`. What happens is:
User clicks `Button` -> `RowCommand` Fires -> Custom event is raised on `UserControl` -> Page detects this and changes the active view index for a `MultiView` and also the page title and some other controls outside the `UpdatePanel`.

The problem is, the page posts back asyncchronously, the page title changes, but the actions requiring a full `PostBack` don't happen because a full `PostBack` doesn't occur.

To register the button as a `PostBack` trigger I'm using:

```
ImageButton btnResults = e.Row.FindControl("btnResults") as ImageButton;
ScriptManager scrCurrent = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
if (btnResults != null && scrCurrent != null) {
    scrCurrent.RegisterPostBackControl(btnResults);
}
```

I know this is a bit of a complicated problem, but I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you post your markup for the imagebutton  ?

Comment: Are there other items in this user control that you want to cause asynch postbacks or is it the button the only thing that causes postbacks?

Comment: Thee button was the only thing. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eventual solution was to use the above code as is, but in the RowCreated event instead of the RowDataBound. Evidently one of the quirks of ASP.NET, sometimes event order is surprising and seemingly unpredictable. For the same reason, I've always found it best to register JavaScript as late as possible, so I usually use the SaveStateComplete event.